# What is the most efficient way to pass the array of values to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the list of data available like this

```
DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))
DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))
DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))
DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))
```

I have to put this as the mark-up of my html page.
I need a way by which I can read the same in javascript from the html mark up.
I tried - `<input type="hidden" value="DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44)) , DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44)) , DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))" />`

and, I tried to read the wanted field like this-

```
$.each(myarray.split(','), function(index, value) { 
      myjavascript_function(value)
    });
```

**Problem**- Using the above `javascript`, I am unable to obtain the above mentioned list of data.

**Question**- How do I put the data list in the markup so as to be able to get the data list in the `javascript/jQuery` as an `Array` or a `Plain object` or any other format?

Comment: From where are you getting the data?

Comment: I think you can use [JSon](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) With [GSon lib](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for server side and jquery json for client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can also try `value="{'data':['DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))' , 'DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))' , 'DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))']}"` like a `html attribute` and get it in the javascript as

`var myPlainObject =  JSON.parse($("someSelector").attr("value"));`

here, `myPlainObject` will be the [plain object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject).

```
var mayArray = myPlainObject .data;
```

u r correct, the format will not become wat we give in the `html attr`(it is coming as a `String` in this case) so, will have to use `JSON.parse()` to get the `plain object` out of the `String`.

Comment: I tried this but then jquery is splitiing every character by character

Comment: are u giving the u enclosing DATA(()) thing in '' and using , to seperate them ?

Comment: no. can you give me the code where it `alert` me the value of array one by one. `myArray[0]` is returning me `[`

Comment: @user2330497 can you format the data in any way you want or is this format set?

Comment: check out the edited Ans.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is through [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Your data could be structured like this, which can easily be printed to a variable on the page served, or returned from an AJAX call which you can then parse:

```
[
  [33,54.4445,66.44,77.44],
  [33,54.4445,66.44,77.44],
  [33,54.4445,66.44,77.44],
  [33,54.4445,66.44,77.44]
]
```

Comment: That data is  avaiable on my page where i am generating the html page. I can insert that anywhere inside html but i can't get json directly via from server via json , as i have to write a separate conroller for that. Is there any other way. i can dump that as json inside hidden text field. will that be ok. After echoing how can i get that back

Comment: @user2330497 what server-side language are you using? If you are using, PHP, you can `echo` a PHP array that is processed through `json_encode`.

Comment: i tried that in hidden the result is `["DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))", "DATA((33,54.4445,66.44,77.44))"]` but i am not able to get the array from there in jquery. i tried this `$.each($("#data").attr("value");, function() {` but then it is splitiing every character

Comment: @user2330497 what is your server-side language?

Comment: `python` and that has buildin function json.dumps(list)